# Let ${a_n}$ and ${b_n}$ be sequences. Prove that if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_n^2 + b_n^2) = 0$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let ${a_n}$ and ${b_n}$ be sequences. Prove that if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_n^2 + b_n^2) = 0$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=0$

This was a question on my Real Analysis undergrad exam. Which I tried to prove by wrongly using the contrapositive. Can someone direct me on the right path?

Comment: I don't see a problem with using the contrapositive. Do you want to show us what you tried?

Comment: We assume $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n \neq 0$. Then by the Algebraic Limit Theorem $a_n \rightarrow a$ for some number other than zero. Then the $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(a_n^2 + b_n^2)\neq 0$. Therefore $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n = 0$

Comment: That's a bit too short. Also, you don't know that $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges. Try to work with the definition of convergence (or better, its negation instead). Also, you get the $\infty$-symbol with `\infty`.

Comment: Will do, thanks martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are dealing with real sequences, notice that for all $n$, one has:
$$0\leqslant {a_n}^2\leqslant{a_n}^2+{b_n}^2.$$
Therefore $(|a_n|^2)_n$ goes to $0$.
Then use the continuity of the square root to conclude.

Comment: I don't understand the $n$ at the end of $(|a_n|^2)_n$. What is its significance? And how do I use the continuity of the square root to conclude?

Comment: The $n$ under $(|a_n|^2)$ means that this is a sequence with respect with $n$, nothing else! Let $f$ be a continuous function, if $x_n\rightarrow x$, then $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$, apply this with $f=\sqrt{\cdot}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Let $\epsilon >0$. If $N$ is such that ${a_n}^2+{b_n}^2 < \epsilon^2$ for all $n >N$, show that 
$$\left| a_n -0 \right| < \epsilon \qquad \forall n >N$$